Find unique value in corrsponding columns

First two column selected compare both column any unique value find in second column  that value only copy and paste below of second column and no need first column unique value, First three column selected compare those three column any unique value find in third column  that value copy and paste below of third column  and no need first and second column unique value, and so on....

Can you show us a data sample and expected result of the data preferably in Markdown?

What do you mean by "if unique value found on selected column"? If there are not duplicates, at all? If all the values are the same?

I add the image beginning of my comment, what i want please refer that

Change the parameters as needed in this formula: (in cell B14) and copy to the right
=UNIQUE(TOCOL(CHOOSECOLS($A$4:$D$10,SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS($A$14:B$14))),3,TRUE),,TRUE)


Note: Now the references are correspond to the posted image.


Use a Dictionary to count the part, then get the list of unique part
The code can catch all cols if your table is expanded in future

Microsoft documentation:

Range.Resize property (Excel)


Worksheet.UsedRange property (Excel)


Dictionary object

Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, sKey
    Dim arrData, arrRes, iR As Long
    Const START_ROW = 4
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set rngData = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    arrData = rngData.Value
    Dim RowCnt As Long: RowCnt = UBound(arrData)
    ' loop through cols
    For j = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData, 2)
        ' loop through rows
        For i = START_ROW To RowCnt
            sKey = arrData(i, j)
            If Len(sKey) > 0 Then
                ' count by Dict
                If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
                    objDic(sKey) = objDic(sKey) + 1
                Else
                    objDic(sKey) = 1
                End If
            End If
        Next
        ' Get the unqiue list for 2nd, 3rd ... Cols
        If j > 1 Then
            ReDim arrRes(1 To RowCnt, 0)
            iR = 0
            For Each sKey In objDic.Keys
                ' get the unique list
                If objDic(sKey) = 1 Then
                    iR = iR + 1
                    arrRes(iR, 0) = sKey
                End If
            Next
            ' write output to sheet
            If iR > 0 Then
                Cells(RowCnt + 2, j).Value = iR
                Cells(RowCnt + 3, j).Resize(iR, 1).Value = arrRes
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub



Update:
Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, sKey
    Dim arrData, arrRes, iR As Long
    Const START_ROW = 4
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set rngData = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    arrData = rngData.Value
    Dim RowCnt As Long: RowCnt = UBound(arrData)
    ' loop through cols
    For j = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData, 2)
        ' loop through rows
        For i = START_ROW To RowCnt
            sKey = arrData(i, j)
            If Len(sKey) > 0 Then
                ' count by Dict
                If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
                    objDic(sKey) = objDic(sKey) + 1
                Else
                    objDic(sKey) = 1
                End If
            End If
        Next
        ' Get the unqiue list for 2nd, 3rd ... Cols
        If j > 1 Then
            ReDim arrRes(1 To RowCnt, 0)
            iR = 0
            For i = START_ROW To RowCnt
                sKey = arrData(i, j)
                If Len(sKey) > 0 Then
                    If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
                        ' get the unique list
                        If objDic(sKey) = 1 Then
                            iR = iR + 1
                            arrRes(iR, 0) = sKey
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            ' write output to sheet
            If iR > 0 Then
                Cells(RowCnt + 2, j).Value = iR
                Cells(RowCnt + 3, j).Resize(iR, 1).Value = arrRes
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub



What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?
What should I do when someone answers my question?

Pardon me Mr. Taller, now I can't ask new question, that's why I ask in comment. All are good but I want one update please could you rewrite that, my update is first two column compare and second column unique value only copy and paste below and then first three colum compare only third colum unique value show below and so on....

It looks like different with your last comment. Please edit your post to share the expected output.

Hi Mr.Taller warm greetings!   i edit my post, what i want finally, kindly review.

Hi Mr. Taller thankyou so much,  really I want to learn VBA, but I can't understand concepts it's really difficult for me, could you give suggestion how to practice VBA and any best resources. Once again thanks.

For Excel users, VBA isn't too difficult to learn compared to other programming languages. I'd recommend starting with basic coding logic and practicing with small projects or tasks. Don't forget that the Record Macro feature of Excel is an awesome tool for any VBA learner. There are lots free resoure online. eg.Free VBA Course. btw,
What should I do when someone answers my question?
